# NpgSQL Obtener columnas en el DataRead

Tags: c#, postgresql

Existe alguna manera de obtener una lista con todas las columnas que se encuentran dentro de un NpgsqlDataReader después de realizar un select a la base de datos?

Es decir:
realizo un select a la base de datos de este estilo:
`SELECT * FROM persona;`

y el resultado lo  almaceno dentro de un NpgsqlDataReader

Cuento con alguna manera de obtener un arreglo o una lista con los nombres de las columnas cargadas?

Comment: yo agarre esa clase.. la escribi en google, me llevo a una documentacion (que supongo que sera de esa clase) y luego lei un poco y encontre esto: GetColumnSchema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tecnicamente, el DataReader es un **lector** de datos desde una fuente de datos, para lo que quieres podrías crear algún [**DataSet, DataTable o DataReader**](https://olgeferrer.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/definicion-de-dataset-dataview-y-datatable/) para almacenar los datos y para lo que quieres hacer existe la siguiente manera:

```
{
 NpgsqlCommand cmd = cn.conexion.CreateCommand();
 cmd.CommandText = "Select * from persona";
 cmd.Prepare();

 NpgsqlDataReader lector = cmd.ExecuteReader;

 schemaTable = myReader.GetSchemaTable();
}
```

Cualquier duda que tengas me avisas, suerte.